# Where does go sms store pictures

Tags: go-sms

I use go sms on my L34c phone.  When I download attached pictures from a message it shows /storage/emulated/0/gosms/download/
I cannot find that on either internal stoarage or my sd card
Please help me find thw downloaded pics.  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, I've turned my comment into an answer -- you can hit the check mark below the voting buttons to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/storage/emulated/0` is the path your device uses to reference your storage space. So if you are browsing the storage/SD card, you can simply look for the `gosms` folder directly.